# Bad CPU type in executable - Jslint

Tags: static-analysis

Has anyone seen this error

```
Bad CPU type in executable
```

When trying to run the executable after installing from http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the industry standard: https://eslint.org/ not... whatever that tool is. That project is abandoned.

Comment: I don't think you want to use whatever this is. As Jose says, it's abandoned. JSLint is [over here](https://jslint.com/) and eslint, probably the most popular javascript linter now, is [here](https://eslint.org/). What are you trying to do?